# Confusion regarding #interrupt-cells configuration on PCA9555 expander

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, interrupt, device-tree

I'm trying to setup a device tree source file for the first time on my custom platform. On the board is a NXP PCA9555 gpio expander. I'm attempting to setup node for the device and am a bit confused.

Here is where I'm at with the node in the dts file:

```
ioexp0: gpio-exp@21 {
        compatible = "nxp,pca9555";
        reg = <21>;

        interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
        interrupts = <8 0>;

        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;

        /*I don't understand the following two lines*/
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <2>;
};
```

I got to this point by using the [armada-388-gp.dts](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/armada-388-gp.dts) source as a guide.

My confusion is on what code processes the `#interrupt-cells` property. The [bindings documentation](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-pca953x.txt) is not very helpful at all for this chip as it doesn't say anything regarding interrupt cell interpretation.

Looking at the `pca953x_irq_setup` function in the [source code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.c#L623) for the pca9555 driver - I don't see anywhere that the `#interrupt-cells` property is handled. Is this handled in the linux interrupt handling code? I'm just confused as to how I'm suppose to know the meaning of the two interrupt cells.

`pca953x_irq_setup` for your convenience:

```
static int pca953x_irq_setup(struct pca953x_chip *chip,
                 int irq_base)
{
    struct i2c_client *client = chip->client;
    int ret, i;

    if (client->irq && irq_base != -1
            && (chip->driver_data & PCA_INT)) {
        ret = pca953x_read_regs(chip,
                    chip->regs->input, chip->irq_stat);
        if (ret)
            return ret;

        /*
         * There is no way to know which GPIO line generated the
         * interrupt.  We have to rely on the previous read for
         * this purpose.
         */
        for (i = 0; i < NBANK(chip); i++)
            chip->irq_stat[i] &= chip->reg_direction[i];
        mutex_init(&chip->irq_lock);

        ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(&client->dev,
                    client->irq,
                       NULL,
                       pca953x_irq_handler,
                       IRQF_TRIGGER_LOW | IRQF_ONESHOT |
                           IRQF_SHARED,
                       dev_name(&client->dev), chip);
        if (ret) {
            dev_err(&client->dev, "failed to request irq %d\n",
                client->irq);
            return ret;
        }

        ret =  gpiochip_irqchip_add_nested(&chip->gpio_chip,
                           &pca953x_irq_chip,
                           irq_base,
                           handle_simple_irq,
                           IRQ_TYPE_NONE);
        if (ret) {
            dev_err(&client->dev,
                "could not connect irqchip to gpiochip\n");
            return ret;
        }

        gpiochip_set_nested_irqchip(&chip->gpio_chip,
                        &pca953x_irq_chip,
                        client->irq);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my first time working with device tree so I'm hoping it's something obvious that I'm just missing.

UPDATE:

As a clarification - I am working with kernel version `4.12-rc4` at the moment.

I now understand that I was misinterpreting some properties of the device tree. I was previously under the impression that the driver had to specify how all properties were handled. I now see that linux will actually handle many of the generic properties such as `gpios` or `interrupts` (which makes a lot of sense).

Here is a bit more of a detailed explanation of how the translation from intspec to `IRQ_TYPE*` happens:

The function `of_irq_parse_one` copies the interrupt specifier integers to a `struct of_phandle_args` [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/drivers/of/irq.c#L354). This arg is then passed to `irq_create_of_mapping` via a consumer function (e.g. `of_irq_get`). This function then maps these args to a `struct irq_fwspec` via `of_phandle_args_to_fwspec` and passes it's fwspec data to `irq_create_fwspec_mapping`. These functions are all found in [irqdomain.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/kernel/irq/irqdomain.c#L590). At this point the irq will belong to an `irq_domain` or use the `irq_default_domain`. As far I can tell - the `pca853x` driver uses the default domain. This domain is often setup by platform specific code. I found mine by searching for `irq_domain_ops` [on cross reference](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/ident/irq_domain_ops). A lot of these seem to do simple copying of `intspec[1] & IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK` to the `type` variable in `irq_create_fwspec_mapping` via `irq_domain_translate`. From here the type is set to the irq's `irq_data` via `irqd_set_trigger_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read section 2 in this: [Specifying interrupt information for devices](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/interrupts.txt) ...

> ### 2) Interrupt controller nodes
>
> A device is marked as an interrupt controller with the "interrupt-controller"
>   property. This is a empty, boolean property. An additional "#interrupt-cells"
>   property defines the number of cells needed to specify a single interrupt.
>
> It is the responsibility of the interrupt controller's binding to define the
>   length and format of the interrupt specifier. The following two variants are
>   commonly used:
>
> a) one cell
>
> ---
>
> The #interrupt-cells property is set to 1 and the single cell defines the
>    index of the interrupt within the controller.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>    vic: intc@10140000 {
>            compatible = "arm,versatile-vic";
>            interrupt-controller;
>            #interrupt-cells = <1>;
>            reg = <0x10140000 0x1000>;
>    };
>
>    sic: intc@10003000 {
>            compatible = "arm,versatile-sic";
>            interrupt-controller;
>            #interrupt-cells = <1>;
>            reg = <0x10003000 0x1000>;
>            interrupt-parent = <&vic>;
>            interrupts = <31>; /* Cascaded to vic */
>    };
> ```
>
> b) two cells
>
> ---
>
> The #interrupt-cells property is set to 2 and the first cell defines the
>    index of the interrupt within the controller, while the second cell is used
>    to specify any of the following flags:
>
> > - bits[3:0] trigger type and level flags
> >
> >   1 = low-to-high edge triggered
> >        2 = high-to-low edge triggered
> >        4 = active high level-sensitive
> >        8 = active low level-sensitive
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>    i2c@7000c000 {
>            gpioext: gpio-adnp@41 {
>                    compatible = "ad,gpio-adnp";
>                    reg = <0x41>;
>
>                    interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
>                    interrupts = <160 1>;
>
>                    gpio-controller;
>                    #gpio-cells = <1>;
>
>                    interrupt-controller;
>                    #interrupt-cells = <2>;
>
>                    nr-gpios = <64>;
>            };
>
>            sx8634@2b {
>                    compatible = "smtc,sx8634";
>                    reg = <0x2b>;
>
>                    interrupt-parent = <&gpioext>;
>                    interrupts = <3 0x8>;
>
>                    #address-cells = <1>;
>                    #size-cells = <0>;
>
>                    threshold = <0x40>;
>                    sensitivity = <7>;
>            };
>    };
> ```

So for the two cell variant, the first number is an index and the second is a bit mask defining the type of the interrupt input.

This part of the device tree is handled by code in `drivers/of/irq.c` (e.g. `of_irq_parse_one()`).

The two lines you refer to in the quoted example declare the device (`gpio-exp@21`) to be an interrupt controller and any other device that wants to use it must provide two cells per interrupt.

Just above those lines is an example of a device specifying an interrupt in another interrupt controller (not this one, but the device with alias `gpio`), via the two properties `interrupt-parent` and `interrupts` (or you could use the new `interrupts-extended` which allows different interrupt controllers for each interrupt by specifying the parent as the first cell of the property).